# Why different styles in same input tag

Tags: html, input, css

Go to http://jsfiddle.net/j2GZP/1/

```
<input type="button" value="type = button">
<input type="text" value="type = text" >
```

I have set a border-radius its working well only on input [type=button] but which styles are Not working input field [type=button] perfectly on Mozilla 21.0
Problems : We can see an another white color in input field edge

screen shot: [image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
input{
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    background:#16A085;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
}
```

`outline:none;` removes the white or red border!

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2GZP/5/).

Comment: Thanks, but no changes, i have added print screen in question  please check

Comment: well, when I checked your fiddle in firefox and chrome both it just works fine!

Comment: i did double check still having problem here on mozilla 21.0

Comment: well i checked it on firefox 19!

Comment: It works fine on my Firefox 21/Win. Maybe your software is not installed correctly or you have a plugin that is probleming! @ShibinRagh

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you're looking for [`outline-style:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j2GZP/4/

Comment: Thanks, but no changes, i have added print screen in question  please check

Comment: Looks just fine on my Firefox (21/Mac). Maybe you have a plugin that interferes?